# Add cursor to second instance of text input

Tags: jquery

I've inherited some slightly iffy code, I have a text input box with the following ID `id="search-orders"`, however a text input box with the same ID also exists in a second area on the same page. I'm attempting to set the focus to the second instance of the text box (the second instance appears below the first)

I have the following which sets the focus on the first instance, is there a way I can neatly modify this to set the focus to the second instance?

```
$( "#search-orders" ).focus();
```

Comment: ID must be unique use class if you want more than one element with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. No feature exists because the standard is only to give one element an ID. Your best way around this problem and to make the code more maintainable in the future is to give the two text boxes different ID's and change any css and javascript associated with that ID.